# Setting up Visual Studio for MPI : Identifier not found error

Tags: c++, mpi, identifier

I try to set up VS2017 to write some MPI programs, and i added all of these libraries like in this tutorial:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/

and try to run simple MPI code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include "stdafx.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And when I build it gives me error that MPI_Init and MPI_Finalize identifiers are not found. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first include. All include directives before `#include "stdafx.h"` are ignored.